# Pressure cooker relationships

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What is a Pressure cooker relationship? I searched for  the meaning on the internet but I could not find any definition.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), like where you found the phrase and a complete sentence.

Comment: I am thinking this might be in a business context, for example [*Wells Fargo's pressure-cooker sales culture comes at a cost*](http://www.latimes.com/business/la-fi-wells-fargo-sale-pressure-20131222-story.html), generally referring to a high pressure sales environment.

Comment: This is a metaphorical term for certain interpersonal relationships, where unexpressed, held-in anger and resentment are ready to "explode".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually

> pressure cooker

is a phrase which is used to describe a highly stressful environment, as the major fear is that the pressure within the cooker continues to grow until it explodes.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Pressure cookers are pots that can be sealed and then heated to cook food under high pressure. If the pressure grows too great, steam escapes from a release valve. Under certain circumstances, the vessel may even explode.

So the analogy is to people who are highly stressed from working under intense pressure; or who have volatile characters, inclining them to explode with angry emotion over small upsets.